# What is the new way of creating sql lite open helper class in android

Tags: android, sql, sqliteopenhelper

I am new in android developer 
I used to use in sql lite open helper but lately I heard about a new way of creating sql lite database (maybe it's not true,  I don't know  )

I will be glad to hear if you guys know something about it.

Thanks :)

Comment: There is no new way, the APIs are the same as they have always been.

Comment: `maybe it's not true, I don't know` **It isn't**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no new way. Here're all main moments for you to work with database in android: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html